# agrear input con boton

Tags: html, html5, script, input, html-tabla

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar si me agrega el otro input pero se borra lo que tengo en la primera

```
<input id="btnAgregar" type="button" value="Agregar" />
<div id="divAgregarInputs">
  <script>
  var btnElem = document.getElementById('btnAgregar');
var index = -1;
btnElem.onclick = function(evt) {
  index++;
  var divAgreg = document.getElementById('divAgregarInputs');
  divAgreg.innerHTML = divAgreg.innerHTML + '<input  " type="text" value="'  + '" /><br />';
}
</script>
```

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373780/c%C3%B3mo-alinear-un-bot%C3%B3n-junto-a-un-input)``
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56561/como-puedo-a%C3%B1adir-un-campo-mediante-un-bot%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```javascript
divAgreg.innerHTML = divAgreg.innerHTML + '<input  " type="text" value="'  + '" /><br />';
```

por esto:

```javascript
divAgreg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'<input type="text" value="" /><br />');
```

donde usamos [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) con su posición, en este caso `beforeend`, para agregar el contenido sin modificar ni releer todo el elemento.

Ejemplo:

```html
<input id="btnAgregar" type="button" value="Agregar" />
<div id="divAgregarInputs">
</div>
<script>
  var btnElem = document.getElementById('btnAgregar');
  var index = -1;
  btnElem.onclick = function(evt) {
    index++;
    var divAgreg = document.getElementById('divAgregarInputs');
    divAgreg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'<input  type="text" value="' + index + '" /><br />');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: funciono gracias

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma muy facil se puede agregar otro contenido al final del mismo.

El contenido de la constante `agregar` debe estar entre backtics ``` `` ```.

Luego con `inerHTML +=` se inserta en el DOM

```js
const btnElem = document.getElementById('btnAgregar');
    const divAgreg = document.getElementById('divAgregarInputs');

    btnElem.onclick = function(evt) {

        const agregar = `
            <input type="text" value="'  + '" /><br />
        `;

        divAgreg.innerHTML += agregar;
    }
```

```html
<input id="btnAgregar" type="button" value="Agregar" />
    <div id="divAgregarInputs">
```

Comment: El problema no era ese exactamente, sinó que si te fijas, si modificas un input y le cambias el valor, al darle otra vez al botón `Agregar`, se borra ese cambio pues se reescribe todo de nuevo con innerHTML.

Comment: Si, ahora entiendo